# Refactor JS array in the specific format the backend is expecting

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, data-structures

I have this array that's returned when a user submits a form:

```
leaders: [
    {
        email: 'name@domain.io',
        sites: [
            {
                name: 'Test',
                sitemeta_id: 'xxxxxxxxx',
                _checked: true
            },
            {
                name: 'Test 2',
                sitemeta_id: 'xxxxxxxx',
                _checked: true
            }
        ],
        focused: false,
        _sitesChecked: 1
    },
    {
        email: 'dog@gmail.com',
        sites: [
            {
                name: 'Some Name',
                sitemeta_id: 'xxxxx',
                _checked: true
            },
            {
                name: 'Names',
                sitemeta_id: 'xxxxxxxx'
            }
        ],
        focused: false,
        _sitesChecked: 2
    }
]
```

I'd like to refactor this to send this array in the specific format the backend is expecting, which would only include site names with the value _checked as true, so the site "Names" wouldn't be included, for example:

```
leaders: [
    {
        email: 'name@domain.io',
        sites: ['Test', 'Test2']
    },
    {
        email: 'dog@gmail.com',
        sites: ['Some Name']
    }
]
```

What's the best way to achieve this in JS (or AngularJS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map` to transform one array into another, and destructure the arguments to reduce syntax noise:

```js
const leaders = [{email:'name@domain.io',sites:[{name:'Test',sitemeta_id:'xxxxxxxxx',_checked:!0},{name:'Test 2',sitemeta_id:'xxxxxxxx'}],focused:!1,_sitesChecked:1},{email:'dog@gmail.com',sites:[{name:'Some Name',sitemeta_id:'xxxxx',_checked:!0},{name:'Names',sitemeta_id:'xxxxxxxx',_checked:!0}],focused:!1,_sitesChecked:2}];

const output = leaders.map(
  ({ email, sites }) => ({
    email,
    sites: sites.reduce(
      (accum, { name, _checked }) => _checked ? [...accum, name] : accum,
      []
    )
  })
);
console.log(output);
```